# How to force geom_bar() bars to start at the origin of the scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's my code for graphing a figure but I cannot figure out how to make the bars START at the graph edge where the labels are. I don't want the white space between the labels on the x-axis and the bars. I know my scale is log so starting at "0" won't work but there should be a way to force the origin to start at 1?

Dput of my work:

```
structure(list(Kingdom = c("Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", 
"Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", 
"Bacteria"), Phylum = c("Pseudomonadota", "Pseudomonadota", "Pseudomonadota", 
"Pseudomonadota", "Pseudomonadota", "Pseudomonadota", "Pseudomonadota", 
"Pseudomonadota", "Pseudomonadota", "Pseudomonadota"), Class = c("Gammaproteobacteria", 
"Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", 
"Alphaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Alphaproteobacteria", 
"Gammaproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Betaproteobacteria"
), Order = c("Enterobacterales", "Enterobacterales", "Enterobacterales", 
"Enterobacterales", "Sphingomonadales", "Xanthomonadales", "Hyphomicrobiales", 
"Pseudomonadales", "Orbales", "Burkholderiales"), Family = structure(150:141, levels = c("???.33", 
"???.34", "Chitinibacteraceae", "Cyclobacteriaceae", "Dysgonomonadaceae", 
"Mycoplasmataceae", "Parvibaculaceae", "Polyangiaceae", "Reyranellaceae", 
"Turicibacteraceae", "Alteromonadaceae", "Beutenbergiaceae", 
"Brucellaceae", "Nitriliruptoraceae", "Peptoniphilaceae", "Streptosporangiaceae", 
"???.30", "???.31", "???.32", "Candidatus Midichloriaceae", "Eubacteriaceae", 
"Methylocystaceae", "Rhodocyclaceae", "???.28", "???.29", "Bifidobacteriaceae", 
"Cellulomonadaceae", "???.25", "???.26", "???.27", "Aeromonadaceae", 
"Azospirillaceae", "Bogoriellaceae", "Chlamydiaceae", "Desulfuromonadaceae", 
"Methylococcaceae", "Propionibacteriaceae", "Hafniaceae", "???.24", 
"Anaplasmataceae", "???.23", "Oceanospirillaceae", "Planococcaceae", 
"Solirubrobacteraceae", "Phyllobacteriaceae", "Pseudobdellovibrionaceae", 
"???.22", "Ornithinimicrobiaceae", "???.21", "Dietziaceae", "Parachlamydiaceae", 
"Pleomorphomonadaceae", "Roseobacteraceae", "Sanguibacteraceae", 
"Zoogloeaceae", "Nakamurellaceae", "???.20", "Hyphomonadaceae", 
"Fusobacteriaceae", "???.19", "Fluviibacteraceae", "Dermabacteraceae", 
"Promicromonosporaceae", "???.18", "Intrasporangiaceae", "Micromonosporaceae", 
"???.17", "Brevibacteriaceae", "Nitrobacteraceae", "Devosiaceae", 
"Flavobacteriaceae", "Gemellaceae", "Vibrionaceae", "Micrococcaceae", 
"Caulobacteraceae", "???.16", "Bacillaceae", "???.15", "???.14", 
"???.13", "???.12", "Aquaspirillaceae", "Actinomycetaceae", "Aerococcaceae", 
"Cytophagaceae", "???.11", "Erythrobacteraceae", "Carnobacteriaceae", 
"Corynebacteriaceae", "???.10", "Spirosomataceae", "Chitinophagaceae", 
"Mycobacteriaceae", "Staphylococcaceae", "Streptomycetaceae", 
"???.9", "Paracoccaceae", "Tsukamurellaceae", "Chromatiaceae", 
"Aurantimonadaceae", "Pasteurellaceae", "???.8", "Deinococcaceae", 
"???.7", "Sphaerotilaceae", "Pseudonocardiaceae", "Neisseriaceae", 
"Rickettsiaceae", "Enterococcaceae", "???.6", "Nocardioidaceae", 
"Geodermatophilaceae", "Halomonadaceae", "Burkholderiaceae", 
"Gordoniaceae", "???.5", "Streptococcaceae", "Lactobacillaceae", 
"Nocardiaceae", "???.4", "Alcaligenaceae", "Roseiflexaceae", 
"Geminicoccaceae", "???.3", "???.2", "Moraxellaceae", "???.1", 
"Rhodanobacteraceae", "Acetobacteraceae", "Weeksellaceae", "Sphingobacteriaceae", 
"Comamonadaceae", "Pectobacteriaceae", "Budviciaceae", "Paenibacillaceae", 
"Acholeplasmataceae", "Kineosporiaceae", "Microbacteriaceae", 
"Hymenobacteraceae", "Rhizobiaceae", "Oxalobacteraceae", "Orbaceae", 
"Pseudomonadaceae", "Methylobacteriaceae", "Xanthomonadaceae", 
"Sphingomonadaceae", "Yersiniaceae", "Morganellaceae", "Enterobacteriaceae", 
"Erwiniaceae"), class = "factor"), MKC09 = c(25649L, 141L, 0L, 
5L, 2192L, 12L, 5404L, 74L, 0L, 120L), MKC100 = c(5826L, 12357L, 
1124L, 147249L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC103 = c(17L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 4562L, 4084L, 796L, 125L, 0L, 4L), MKC104 = c(21L, 97L, 
0L, 14L, 3676L, 152L, 2133L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC105 = c(19667L, 
3313L, 0L, 0L, 48L, 885L, 317L, 587L, 0L, 479L), MKC106 = c(26055L, 
10766L, 114L, 17L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 24L, 0L, 0L), MKC109 = c(177L, 
15L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC110 = c(134915L, 185L, 
8L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC115 = c(3831L, 397L, 0L, 
0L, 2918L, 85L, 1546L, 71L, 0L, 520L), MKC12 = c(28367L, 203L, 
0L, 3L, 1733L, 0L, 1424L, 352L, 0L, 2L), MKC123 = c(21765L, 29519L, 
1256L, 408L, 3L, 0L, 28L, 0L, 8748L, 0L), MKC131 = c(39780L, 
1199L, 0L, 4L, 80L, 46L, 14L, 58L, 0L, 1045L), MKC132 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 27L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC137 = c(182L, 28688L, 
0L, 0L, 80L, 0L, 129L, 16L, 0L, 48L), MKC140 = c(11L, 14L, 0L, 
0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC141 = c(4352L, 351L, 142L, 0L, 
1718L, 22L, 7292L, 65L, 0L, 9L), MKC144 = c(205L, 40L, 0L, 0L, 
3547L, 0L, 409L, 533L, 0L, 24L), MKC146 = c(8L, 33L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC147 = c(8288L, 5461L, 45L, 32L, 27L, 
3L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 112L), MKC154 = c(11L, 36L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), MKC156 = c(148L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), MKC158 = c(9L, 23L, 6L, 0L, 6809L, 120L, 4264L, 31L, 0L, 
0L), MKC167A = c(27160L, 10651L, 550L, 9L, 434L, 0L, 26L, 215L, 
0L, 199L), MKC167B = c(18L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), MKC171 = c(20066L, 1860L, 0L, 9L, 699L, 0L, 0L, 536L, 0L, 
1061L), MKC175 = c(96498L, 54614L, 2378L, 0L, 76L, 7L, 12L, 0L, 
0L, 41L), MKC184 = c(16L, 32L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), MKC199 = c(4576L, 398L, 0L, 11L, 103L, 0L, 22L, 428L, 0L, 
0L), MKC200 = c(3538L, 2067L, 11L, 0L, 332L, 20L, 1852L, 120L, 
0L, 526L), MKC201 = c(0L, 17L, 0L, 17L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), MKC203 = c(19L, 83L, 0L, 0L, 6818L, 66L, 2596L, 0L, 0L, 3L
), MKC211 = c(26854L, 145783L, 2697L, 204L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), MKC212 = c(0L, 11L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC214 = c(84017L, 
29864L, 60L, 31L, 2L, 5L, 13L, 6L, 0L, 0L), MKC226 = c(0L, 11L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC227 = c(0L, 11L, 6L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC231 = c(0L, 37L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 2L, 
3L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC232 = c(2728L, 11932L, 1812L, 735L, 157L, 
240L, 1690L, 14L, 0L, 498L), MKC233 = c(69L, 13L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC238 = c(1453L, 2220L, 40L, 0L, 15L, 0L, 
8L, 0L, 0L, 23L), MKC241 = c(5028L, 874L, 11L, 0L, 168L, 4L, 
6L, 7465L, 0L, 541L), MKC242 = c(7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), MKC244k = c(99L, 291L, 57808L, 117L, 12L, 0L, 5L, 
7L, 0L, 0L), MKC245a = c(3L, 27L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), MKC246 = c(6647L, 1299L, 111L, 0L, 7910L, 0L, 356L, 1079L, 
7L, 10L), MKC248 = c(14436L, 7232L, 3L, 0L, 86L, 0L, 3L, 14L, 
0L, 0L), MKC252 = c(12661L, 433L, 0L, 0L, 255L, 89L, 73L, 102L, 
0L, 474L), MKC253 = c(21370L, 61483L, 4L, 84L, 7L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
0L, 3L), MKC257 = c(97L, 42L, 208L, 0L, 17L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), MKC258 = c(38561L, 22671L, 781L, 13L, 165L, 339L, 104L, 
183L, 0L, 0L), MKC267 = c(79L, 168L, 0L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
0L, 0L), MKC268 = c(11572L, 23544L, 154L, 56L, 735L, 2L, 3575L, 
11L, 0L, 11L), MKC269 = c(16L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 1958L, 68L, 1396L, 
13L, 0L, 365L), MKC271 = c(12770L, 3870L, 0L, 0L, 15649L, 118L, 
268L, 75L, 0L, 451L), MKC276 = c(0L, 9L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L), MKC279 = c(25200L, 3717L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 368L, 
0L, 6L), MKC314 = c(3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    MKC335 = c(12208L, 935L, 4L, 0L, 1322L, 4L, 2074L, 502L, 
    0L, 67L), MKC336 = c(8942L, 11516L, 4569L, 496L, 87L, 0L, 
    46L, 0L, 0L, 12L), MKC342 = c(6410L, 37198L, 24L, 63L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 41L, 0L, 0L), MKC343 = c(8L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC344 = c(10983L, 77625L, 1042L, 3858L, 
    0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC345 = c(113L, 15366L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 3L), MKC351 = c(19L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC352 = c(26627L, 1927L, 3071L, 79L, 
    5L, 21L, 14L, 19L, 0L, 34L), MKC353 = c(7L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 
    3038L, 6L, 6877L, 4L, 0L, 0L), MKC354 = c(4557L, 2635L, 14830L, 
    89L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 3L), MKC355 = c(15L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 6L), MKC356 = c(69547L, 21633L, 131L, 
    0L, 28L, 48L, 7L, 35L, 0L, 4L), MKC364 = c(32L, 0L, 17L, 
    0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC365 = c(448L, 405L, 16857L, 
    148L, 56L, 66L, 49L, 0L, 0L, 87L), MKC366 = c(48L, 62L, 88L, 
    21L, 40L, 46606L, 3L, 49L, 0L, 536L), MKC367 = c(350L, 5050L, 
    5570L, 247L, 55L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 25L), MKC39 = c(0L, 28L, 
    7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC40 = c(3730L, 16L, 14L, 
    56L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 196L, 0L, 9L), MKC428 = c(31L, 39L, 23L, 
    17L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC429 = c(9921L, 264L, 1021L, 
    0L, 279L, 144L, 79L, 5L, 0L, 154L), MKC430 = c(25L, 1893L, 
    130285L, 819L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC44 = c(0L, 32L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC500 = c(35364L, 3522L, 
    736L, 481L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 0L), MKC67 = c(10190L, 
    5L, 0L, 0L, 56L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 0L, 221L), MKC68 = c(6396L, 
    455L, 5L, 0L, 48L, 99L, 207L, 23L, 0L, 3L), MKC76 = c(3667L, 
    2180L, 8L, 0L, 323L, 3L, 86L, 198L, 0L, 0L), MKC77 = c(16L, 
    16L, 14L, 75L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 428L, 0L, 0L), MKC84 = c(1587L, 
    191853L, 186L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC88 = c(53252L, 
    3696L, 114L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC90 = c(3213L, 
    90L, 6L, 9L, 0L, 7L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 54L), MKC93 = c(34010L, 
    3020L, 12L, 0L, 76L, 0L, 1378L, 116L, 0L, 0L), Total = c(1036561L, 
    859597L, 247976L, 155555L, 68445L, 53398L, 46668L, 14200L, 
    8755L, 7795L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

And my code:

```
ggplot(data10, aes(x=Family, y=Total)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill="red") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans="log10", limits=c(1,2000000), labels=scales::comma) +
  theme(text=element_text(size=13)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=12)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=12)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Total), hjust=-0.1)
```

Image of my figure, but I don't want that gap. I just want the bars to touch the axis line.

[image]

Comment: Try with `scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .05)))` to set the default expansion of the scale to 0 at the lower end.

Comment: Oh nice, that worked well. Thank you!